# how use JComboBox with Class value

Tags: java, class, user-interface, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I have made this:

```
private JComboBox vehicleType = new JComboBox();
DefaultComboBoxModel<Class> dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Class>( 
        new Class[] {Truck.class, Trailer.class, RoadTractor.class, SemiTrailer.class, Van.class, Car.class})
{
    @Override
    public String getSelectedItem() {
        return ((Class<?>)super.getSelectedItem()).getSimpleName();
    }

};
```

And I have obtained this:

[image]

How you can see, the selected item show his simple class name, but in the list... doesn't. How I can make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JComboBox` uses the `toString()` method to get the label, you can override the behavior by implementing a `ListCellRenderer`.

```
vehicleType.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if(value != null) {
            setText(((Class)value).getSimpleName());
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Also if you use this method you should remove the override of `getSelectedItem()` in your model as it will interfere with the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

When filling the comboBox, by default, the `toString()` method of all elements is called.
The `toString()` method of Class returns the full class Name as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#toString%28%29).
In the `getSelectedItem()` method, you call `getSimpleName()` which of course returns the simple name of the class.

To solve your Problem, you need to create a custom [list cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), and overwrite `getListCellRendererComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).